# Centre of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

How do we define a centre of curvature for a space (3D) curve? Is it defined from some evolute? Which one? 
My question is provoked by the statement of the theorem of Meusnier.

Comment: I have an more naïve question: given a space curve, can you say that the curve "near" a point is contained in a plane? If so you could define the center of curvature as you do with 2D curves, as the center of the osculating circle

Comment: This should be the so called "osculating plane". In the proof I am reading they are actually using this definition. But I am a bit confused. I thought the centres of curvature are some evolute (as in the plane case).

Comment: What does "evolute" mean?

Comment: The definition of "evolute" to a curve $c$ in my book is the following - to each point of the curve attach some normal line (line orthogonal to the tangent of the curve) in such a way that the formed surface is a tangent developable for some curve. This curve we call evolute of $c$. The choice of the normal lines is not unique. There are infinitely many evolutes for a curve. For a plane curve one of the evolutes is exactly the centres of curvature. What is confusing me is that if we define the centre of curvature in the same way for a space curve, then there is no evolute which contains it.

Answer (score 2):

The evolute of a plane curve is defined as the locus of the centers of the osculating circles to the curve. The space curve analog of an osculating circle is an osculating sphere.

Let $\pmb\alpha(t):(a,b)\to \Bbb R^3$ be a regular space curve, and let $a < t_0 < b$
be such that $\kappa[\alpha](t_0)\neq 0$ and $\tau[\alpha](t_0)\neq 0$, where $\kappa\neq 0$ is the curvature of the curve $\pmb \alpha(t)$ and $\tau$ is the torsion. Then the **osculating sphere** of $\pmb \alpha(t)$ at $\pmb \alpha(t_0)$ is the unique sphere which has at least order 3 contact with $\pmb \alpha$ at $\pmb \alpha(t_0)$.

Then the *osculating sphere at* $\pmb \alpha(t_0)$ is a sphere of **radius**
$$
R= \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\kappa[\alpha](t_0)}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\kappa'[\alpha](t_0)}{||\alpha'(t_0)|| \kappa^2[\alpha](t_0)\tau[\alpha](t_0)}\right)^2}
$$
and center
$$
\pmb C=\pmb\alpha(t_0)+\frac{1}{\kappa[\alpha](t_0)}\pmb N(t_0)-\frac{\kappa'[\alpha](t_0)}{||\alpha'(t_0)|| \kappa^2[\alpha](t_0)\tau[\alpha](t_0)}\pmb B(t_0)
$$
where $\pmb N(t)$ and $\pmb B(t)$ are the normal and binormal vectors.

We call $R$ *radius of curvature* an $\pmb C$ *centre of curvature* of the curve $\alpha$ at $\alpha](t_0)$.

It is natural to define the evolute of a space curve to be the locus of the centers of the osculating spheres.

The *evolute* of a regular space curve $\pmb\alpha(t):(a,b)\to \Bbb R^3$ is the curve given by
$$
\pmb\beta(t)=\pmb\alpha(t)+\frac{1}{\kappa[\alpha](t)}\pmb N(t)-\frac{\kappa'[\alpha](t)}{||\alpha'(t)|| \kappa^2[\alpha](t)\tau[\alpha](t)}\pmb B(t)
$$
that is, $\pmb\beta(t)$ is the locus of the centers of the osculating spheres.

Comment: Using the definition I wrote above we obtain a similar formula (maybe the same but I will not check it). So you say that the centre of curvature is the centre of osculating sphere and the centre of that sphere could be obtained using this formula?

Comment: For fixed $t=t_0$ you have a centre of an osculating sphere. Collecting all centres varying $t$ you will obtain a curve, said evolute, that contain all these centres and the equation is $\pmb\beta(t)$.

Comment: My initial question is what do we call a "centre of curvature" for a space curve.

Comment: [Here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~palais/dnamath/04gm_curves.pdf) the centre of curvature is defined as in the plane case. Thus defined osculating circle is the section of the sphere you are talking about and the osculating plane. It seems like Meusnier's theorem considers this definition.